# Jenkins select changesets job for pipeline build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to build a Jenkins Pipeline job.

My job is taking code from 2 repositories and doing some other stuff,
on the end it should send email notification with changeset from first repository.
Due to multiple SCM jobs it is saying that there are no changes.

How could I select to get changes from my first job?

Comment: Update. Now I have pipeline with only 1 step using SCM and changes still are not catched by the pipeline job.

Comment: Which SCM are you using? Git? Mercurial? Are those public or private repositories? Do you have 2FA (like https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/securing-your-account-with-two-factor-authentication-2fa) activated on the remote hosting SCM server?

Comment: @VonC, I'm using SVN and Git repositories. They are private. I'm able to get the sources from the repository and I can see in single job "changes history" but not in the pipeline which is "parent" job.

Comment: Could you please provide more info about your overall setup? A screenshot of your Jenkins job would already help.

Comment: So you've a job 1 which calls 2 other jobs A and B. and each of the downstream jobs has configs to pull changes from 2 different repository respectively. And when both the downstream project run is completed, you wanted only the changesets from job A to be sent via email notifier in Job 1? Is that your question?

Comment: Is this your build job, is it a jenkins pipeline or a free style project?

Comment: Do you have some groovy script which is doing `Other Stuff` on your repositories so that we can have a clean picture on what do you really want?

Comment: Sorry for lack of updates.I gave up this approach not to waste time and put everything into single job. But answering @vijay question - exactly as you wrote. I have jobs A and B and trying to run them using job C (pipeline job), and when pipeline will be completed I would like to send a notification with changesets. Problem is because i'm pulling repository in job A and sending notifications in job B, so job B didn't see any changesets.

Answer (score 0):

After cloning the first repository you can insert in your pipeline a stage like this:

```
stage("Do stuff") {
  when{
    changeset "file.js"
  }
  steps {
    script {
      //do stuff
    }
  }
}
```

Other examples on https://pillsfromtheweb.blogspot.com/2020/07/execute-jenkins-pipeline-step-basing-on.html